# How to use the switch statement?

Tags: java

I have a problem using switch statement when I tried to deal with a special situation. For example, I have 3 cases: A, B, C.

for A, I want to do statement_1 and statement_3.
for B, I want to do statement_2 and statement_3.
for C, I want to do nothing
if I use if-else statement, it will look like this:

```
if ( not Car){
    do statement_3

   if Bag
      do statement 2
   else if Apple
      do statement 1

 }
```

when i try to do it from switch statement im getting trouble

```
switch (variable){
  case A:  do statement_1
  case B: do statement_2
// how to do statement 3 here?  
}
```

Comment: what `getting trouble` means exectly?

Comment: have you use `break;`

Comment: please add an [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

The default section handles all values that are not explicitly handled by one of the case statements.

```
switch(var){
    case A:
        //do stuff
        break;
    case B:
        //do stuff
        break;
    default:
        //do stuff
        break;
}
```

EDIT: I have just read the question again and I think I understood you, if you want to "do statement_1 and statement_3 for A and statement_2 and statement_3 for B" you just have to write it:

```
switch(var){
    case A:
        statement_1
        statement_3
        break;
    case B:
        statement_2
        statement_3
        break;
}
```

Comment: I'm flagging this as not being an answer because it's lacking any informational text. edit: After your last edit it contains text, but this doesn't explain your code nor answers it the question (which itself is unclear to me)

Comment: I was writting, just added my answer before having it ended, missclick

Answer (score 0):

I guess you forgot to add a break statement. For example if `expression == A` and you don't have break all statements will be executed, whereas if you add `break`, it will not execute the rest of the cases. Also, the default is the one which is executed if expression doesn't satisfy any of the cases.

```
switch(expression){
    case A:
        statement_1
        statement_3
        break;
    case B:
        statement_1
        statement_2
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For each case, you have to write all the required "statements" and then add `break;` otherwise the next case will be also executed:

```
switch (variable) {
    case A:  
        statement_1;
        statement_3;
        break;
    case B: 
        statement_2;
        statement_3;
        break;
    case C:  
    default: 
        break;    
}
```

Here default case and `C` case are the same and do nothing.